# IIS Rules edit programmatically

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting

I have question about rules in IIS for redirects. Can they be edited by user, thru some web page?
So I want to give user to edit this rule:

```
<rules>
     <rule name="Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="(.*)"/>
         <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^Example.com"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.hr/{R:1}"/>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

But not from IIS, thru web page. It would be good if it would be all saved in database.
DbProvider is only partially good

Answer (score 0):

I did not figure it out how to do this directly. The only solution is to get data from database and then write it to config file. This can be done thru ServerManager and its ConfigurationElement and ConfigurationElementCollection